# Set up IPC using spawn instead of fork

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, child-process

Using this IPC is set up by default between parent node process and child node process:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const k = cp.fork(childPath);
```

I can send a message to the child process:

```
k.send('foobar');
```

and received a message back:

```
k.on('message', m => console.log('received a message from child:',m));
```

however, my question is - is there a way to set-up IPC with a node.js child process using **cp.spawn** instead of cp.fork?

Comment: `spawn` is different from `fork` exactly because fork establishes a communication channel to the child process, and wires up the EventEmitter so we can use `send` on the forked process to exchange messages. `spaws` does not do that, and it is by design

Comment: hey Rodrigo, you are right, that's why I asked the question, to see what would be necessary to make it possible

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to pass in messages to the child process using the `EventEmitter` framework when you use `spawn`. This is exactly the purpose of `fork`, and what makes it different from `spawn`.

See the snippet below from the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options):

> The child_process.fork() method is a special case of child_process.spawn() used specifically to spawn new Node.js processes. Like child_process.spawn(), a ChildProcess object is returned. The returned ChildProcess will have an additional communication channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back and forth between the parent and child. See subprocess.send() for details.

There could possibly be an option to poke with a custom wrap over `spawn` to "augment" its capability to use `EventEmitter`, but I don't see a reason why one wouldn't just use `fork` for its intended use-case instead.

Comment: Of course it is possible to add the wrapper. Fork **is** the wrapper: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/fee0601674556ab240ba8b4383196b1fb1ac0169/lib/child_process.js#L123 just 50 lines that do exactly that - prepare the parameters and call `spawn` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to achieve IPC with `cp.spawn` using a named pipe which are created using the `net` module.

Parent:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`received a message from child: ${data}`);
  });
});

server.listen('my_pipe', () => {
  const child = cp.spawn('node', ['child.js'], {
    stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc'],
  });

  child.send({ path: 'my_pipe' });
});
```

Child:

```
const net = require('net');

process.on('message', (message) => {
  const client = net.createConnection(message.path, () => {
    client.write('hi from child');
  });
});
```

Named pipes are used in the context of Windows and are not directly supported in the same way on UNIX-like systems.For that use UNIX domain sockets for IPC.

Parent:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const net = require('net');
const fs = require('fs');

const SOCKET_PATH = './my_socket';

// Remove the socket file if it already exists
if (fs.existsSync(SOCKET_PATH)) {
  fs.unlinkSync(SOCKET_PATH);
}

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`received a message from child: ${data}`);
  });
});

server.listen(SOCKET_PATH, () => {
  const child = cp.spawn('node', ['child.js'], {
    stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc'],
  });

  child.send({ path: SOCKET_PATH });
});
```

Child:

```
const net = require('net');

process.on('message', (message) => {
  const client = net.createConnection(message.path, () => {
    client.write('hi from child');
  });
});
```

Comment: Be aware that this is a superficial re-implementation of `fork`. The actual implementation takes care of important corner cases, [see](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/fee0601674556ab240ba8b4383196b1fb1ac0169/lib/child_process.js).